# Grouping array values before entering into database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have a symfony app using doctrine2 and I have this array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 7 [createdOn] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2011-03-01))                                        
[1] => Array ( [id] => 9 [createdOn] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2011-03-12))
)
```

amd I need the [id] values to be entered into the database grouped by month like this:

```
| createdOn | id    |
| 2011-03   | {7, 9}|
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an array with the required format;

```
foreach($array as $index => $subArray){
  $yearMonth = subStr($subArray["date"], 0, 7);
  $newData[$yearMonth][] = $subArray["id"];
}

foreach($newData as $yearMonth => $subArray){
  $newData[$yearMonth] = "{".implode(",", $newData[$yearMonth])."}";
}

var_dump($newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the part of your doctrine query builder:

```
$date = explode('-', $array[0]['date']);
$fromDate = new \DateTime($date[0].'-'.$date[1].'-'01 00:00:00); // 2011-03-01 00:00:00
$toDate = $fromDate;
$toDate->modify('+1 month'); // 2011-04-01 00:00:00

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
     ->select('a.id')
     ->where('a.createdOn >= :fromDate')
     ->andWhere('a.createdOn < :toDate') // strictly inferior
     ->setParameter('fromDate', $fromDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
     ->setParameter('toDate', $toDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

With this query, you search id of entities that have a createdOn date between "2011-03-01 00:00:00" (include) and "2011-04-01 00:00:00" (exclude), so a createdOn in march !

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$res           = array();
foreach($your_array as $val){
    $dt        = new DateTime($val['createdOn']->date); 
    $res[$dt->format('Y-m')][] = $val['id'];
}

foreach($res as &$val){
   $val        = json_encode($val);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a doctrine event listener as described on
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html and add the ids to another database.